# share it button doesn't work ios 7 xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

i'm trying to make two buttons in one new viewcontroller, one for facebook and the other one for twitter. I'only want to make a simple post for each one.
The problem is when i follow this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/ and i use it on my new xcode 5 project it doesn't do nothing. I don't know if there's a new way tho share content in xcode5/ios7 but for now can't find a way. If anyone knows how can i fix it it would be great. thank you in advance.
Marc

Comment: what is your problem button not display or not share your data..

Comment: doesn't seem to do the function to open the facebook or twitter pages..

Comment: i have the same issue... apparently the ios 6 code is not working in the ios 7 simulator

Answer (score 0):

- There is a sample project for sharing images and text on Facebook and
  Twitter .
- Please go through it .If you have any query ask me.
  [Here](https://github.com/jayaprada-behera/SocialFrameworkDemo-on-sharing-Images)